# LARAVEL7 uploading image but not showing in page

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-blade

I'm trying to upload an image for every product with a normal crud form

with this code i can see that i upload the images in storage>app>uploads

i can see in phpMyAdmin that the same name i see in VScode (example 185138_1616528993.png )
is showing there but i get broken image in browser. i dont know what to do anymore

This is the store function

```
        $newProduct = Product::make($request -> all());
        $color = Color::findOrFail($request['color_id']);

        $img = $request -> file('imgpro');

        $ext = $img -> getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = rand(100000, 999999) . '_' . time();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . $ext;

        $img -> storeAs('uploads/', $fileName);
        $newProduct -> imgpro = $fileName;

        $newProduct -> color() -> associate($color);

        $newProduct -> save();
        return redirect() -> route('product-show', $newProduct -> id);//  route('product-index');



 
        return redirect() -> route('product-show', $newProduct -> id);//  route('product-index');
```

this is the product-show.blade.php

```
    <img src="{{ asset('/public/uploads/' . $product -> imgpro) }}"  alt="imgpro">

    <img src="{{ asset('/storage/app/uploads/' . $product->imgpro) }}" alt="imgpro2">

    <img src="{{ asset( $product -> imgpro )}}" alt="imgpro3">

    <img src="{{ $product -> imgpro }}" alt="boh">
```

i did the phpartisan storage

Comment: check your network tab in inspect tools and see the returned code of image, if it is 404 then it means that the file is not available under your path

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line of code to store image

```
if(request()->hasFile('imgpro'))
{
    $image = $request['imgpro'];
    $imagename = rand(100000,999999).'-'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    request()->file('image')->storeAs('uploads/',$imagename); 
    $newproduct->imgpro = $imagename;
}
```

In Blade File upend following code

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/uploads/'.$product->image) }}">
```